# AWS Apache flink, application not running in aws, But works in local. What could be the issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dependencies, apache-flink, pyflink, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am using to build an application which gets data from kinesis data stream and sending that data to an external database using endpoint. I used python table API to achieve this, When i run the following code it works in my local system. As i had mutliple jar files, i had combine them together as a fat jar to read the dependency. however if i deploy the application in aws managed apache flink. the job is not running. what could be the potential issue? The cloud watch logs weren't that conclusive.

```
tfrom pyflink.table import EnvironmentSettings, TableEnvironment
import os
import json


# 1. Creates a Table Environment
env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode()
table_env = TableEnvironment.create(env_settings)

statement_set = table_env.create_statement_set()

APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH = "/etc/flink/application_properties.json"  # on kda

is_local = (
    True if os.environ.get("IS_LOCAL") else False
)  # set this env var in your local environment

if is_local:
    # only for local, overwrite variable to properties and pass in your jars delimited by a semicolon (;)
    APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH = "application_properties.json"  # local

    CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    table_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string(
        "pipeline.jars",
        "file:///" + CURRENT_DIR + "/lib/mydep.jar",
        )

def get_application_properties():
    if os.path.isfile(APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH):
        with open(APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH, "r") as file:
            contents = file.read()
            properties = json.loads(contents)
            return properties
    else:
        print('A file at "{}" was not found'.format(APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH))


def property_map(props, property_group_id):
    for prop in props:
        if prop["PropertyGroupId"] == property_group_id:
            return prop["PropertyMap"]

def create_source_table(table_name, stream_name, region, stream_initpos):
    """
    Defines the Kinesis source table schema and configuration.
    """
    return f"""
    CREATE TABLE {table_name} (
        Trial_ID VARCHAR(255),
        PC_Time_s DOUBLE,
        Arduino_Time_ms BIGINT,
        Resistivity_ohm DOUBLE,
        Temperature_C DOUBLE,
        PWM_value BIGINT
    )
    PARTITIONED BY (Trial_ID)
    WITH (
        'connector' = 'kinesis',
        'stream' = '{stream_name}',
        'aws.region' = '{region}',
        'scan.stream.initpos' = '{stream_initpos}',
        'format' = 'json',
        'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601'
    )
    """

def create_jdbc_sink_table(table_name, url, username, password):

    return f"""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (
        Trial_ID VARCHAR(255),
        PC_Time_s DOUBLE,
        Arduino_Time_ms BIGINT,
        Resistivity_ohm DOUBLE,
        Temperature_C DOUBLE,
        PWM_value BIGINT
    ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'jdbc',
        'url' = '{url}',
        'table-name' = '{table_name}',
        'username' = '{username}',
        'password' = '{password}'
    )
    """

def main():

    # Application Property Keys
    input_property_group_key = "consumer.config.0"

    # Table names
    input_table_name = "input_table"
    output_table_name = "trainingdata"

    input_stream_key = "input.stream.name"
    input_region_key = "aws.region"
    input_starting_position_key = "flink.stream.initpos"

    # get application properties
    props = get_application_properties()

    input_property_map = property_map(props, input_property_group_key)

    # Replace with your MySQL connection details
    DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://***string**/db_name"
    DATABASE_USERNAME = "username"
    DATABASE_PASSWORD = "password"


    input_stream = input_property_map[input_stream_key]
    input_region = input_property_map[input_region_key]
    stream_initpos = input_property_map[input_starting_position_key]

    # 4. Create a Kinesis source table
    table_env.execute_sql(
        create_source_table(input_table_name, input_stream, input_region, stream_initpos)
    )

    # 5. Create a JDBC sink table for MySQL database
    table_env.execute_sql(
        create_jdbc_sink_table(output_table_name, DATABASE_URL, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD)
    )

    # 6. Insert data from Kinesis stream to MySQL table
    table_result = table_env.execute_sql(
        " INSERT INTO {0} SELECT * FROM {1}".format(output_table_name, input_table_name)
    )
    # 7. Wait for job completion (local mode) or print job status
    if is_local:
        table_result.wait()
    else:
        # get job status through TableResult
        print(table_result.get_job_client().get_job_status())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried using fat jar and uploaded in to s3 as a zip of whole python dir, and uploaded to apache flink it is not working. However if i run the code form [github](https://github.com/aws-samples/pyflink-getting-started/tree/main/pyflink-examples/GettingStarted) here. it works.